# How to use Recycleview with Rxjava and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

i tried googling to figureout some way to get the values from network call to Recyclerview. But i was not able to figure out how can set the values to adapter using Rxjava

```
private void initViews()
{
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    loadRxjava();

}

private void loadRxjava()
{
    Subscription sub = retrofitManager.getModelNew().postRawJson()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ModelNew>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ModelNew modelNew)
                {

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: can you add the adapter's code?

Answer (score 0):

This it could be a starter

```
   Observable.just(findViewById(R.id.recycler_view))
            .map( o -> (RecyclerView) o)
            .map(recyclerview -> 
                    {recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
                     return recyclerview;
                    })
            .flatMap(recyclerview -> Observable.just(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()))
                    .map(layout -> {
                        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layout)
                                return recyclerview;

                    }))
            .subscribe(recyclerview -> { retrofitManager.getModelNew().postRawJson();
      //TODO:Here you can mix recyclerview with modelView})
```

I dont know what your code does, so not sure if this is what you´re looking for.

If you want to see practicle example of RXJava take a look here https://github.com/politrons/reactive